# Delete records of a TableView inside a UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, uiview, edit

I'm trying to implement a TableView inside a UIView in Storyboard.
This is what I've achieved:

[image]

Now I want that the Edit button, if pressed, prepare table rows for deletion.
I put the Edit button on the Bar wit the following:

```
//add edit button
[buttons addObject:self.editButtonItem];
```

Moreover I've set the tableview delegate and datasource to the main view and events are fired. But how can I tell to the edit button that the rows of the table must be deletable?

Thank you in advance,
yassa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this delegate tabelView method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //some other bookkeeping stuff
}
```

Added code for the Edit buttton when pressed.  Rename "toggleEdit" to whatever to fit your needed.

```
- (IBAction)toggleEdit:(id)sender   //this method should get called when Edit is pressed
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];


//The if ... else part is optional.  You might need to make some change to fit your's.
//    if (self.tableView.editing)
//        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
//    else
//        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Delete"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already implemented the delegated method. My problem is that I don't know how to refer the Edit button to my table inside my view...